# Confusion in range of enums

Tags: c++, enums

How to find the range of enums ?
I have got two versions which state it differently when the lowest value is negative.Stroustrup says that for

```
 enum e3 { min = -10 , max = 1000000 }; // range -1048576:1048575
```

but 
C++ Primer Plus 5th edition says

> for eg if the smallest enumerator is -6, the next power of two [times a minus sign] is -8, and thus the lower limit is -7

I am confused which is correct ?

Comment: I don't know in what way this information is useful (ie. the range) ? even after reading the "cryptic" explanation in Stroustrup's book, I don't know how I can use that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe both are correct (see below for Primer's definition, though), depending on how compatible you want to are. The formal definition is

> For an enumeration where e min is the smallest enumerator and e max is the largest, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type in the range b min to b max , where b min and b max are, respectively, the smallest and largest values of the smallest bit-field that can store e min and e max .

For negative numbers, the question is what representation we use. The footnote to it says

> On a two’s-complement machine, b
>   max is the smallest value greater than or equal to max (abs(e min ) − 1 ,abs(e max ) ) of the form
>   2 M − 1; b is zero if e is non-negative and − (b + 1 ) otherwise.

If you assume sign magnitude or one's complement then the example enumeration's range is `-1048575:1048575`. For two's complement you get one more in the negative range. Primer's definiton lacks the maximum enumerator value, so I'm not sure how it comes to lower limit `-7`. If you want to be maximum compatible with other implementations, I would go with `-1048575:1048575`.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard says (§[dcl.enum]/7):

> Otherwise, for an enumeration where *e<sub>min</sub>* is the smallest enumerator and *e<sub>max</sub>* is the largest, the values of the enumeration are the values in the range *b<sub>min</sub>* to *b<sub>min</sub>*, defined as follows:
>
> - Let *K* be 1 for a two’s complement representation ....
> - *b<sub>max</sub>* is the smallest value greater than or equal to max(|*e<sub>min</sub>*| − *K*, |*e<sub>max</sub>*|) and equal to 2<sup>*M*</sup> − 1, where *M* is a non-negative integer.
> - *b<sub>min</sub>* is zero if *e<sub>min</sub>* is non-negative and −(*b<sub>max</sub>* + *K*) otherwise.

For example, in the first case,

- *e<sub>min</sub>* = -10, *e<sub>max</sub>* = 1000000
- Thus *b<sub>max</sub>* ≥ max(10 − 1, 1000000) = 1000000
- *b<sub>max</sub>* must be of the form 2<sup>*M*</sup> − 1, so we use *M* = 20 ⇒ *b<sub>max</sub>* = 1048575
- *e<sub>min</sub>* is negative, so *b<sub>min</sub>* = −(1048575 + 1) = −1048576.

In the second case,

- *e<sub>min</sub>* = -6, *e<sub>max</sub>* = unspecified
- Thus *b<sub>max</sub>* ≥ max(6 − 1, unspecified) = 5 or more
- If that unspecified is indeed less than 5, then *b<sub>max</sub>* must be 7, and *b<sub>min</sub>* is -8.
- However, if that unspecified number is >7, then the range will be wider.

Therefore, C++ Primer is incorrect, since it ignores the effect of the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

They are exactly same statements, just using different scales. To store number 1000000 you need 20 bits, so your range is -1048576 to +1048575. To store -6 you need 3 bits, so the range you can store in those 3 bits is -8 to +7.